# Principle Relative Curvature

Tags: differential-geometry

Calculate the principal relative curvatures of the surface $y = x\tan\left(\frac{z}{a}\right)$. I have checked in my textbook, but the only definition of relative curvature I could find is $k = \left|\frac{d^2r}{ds^2}\right|$ and am unsure about how to solve this problem given this equation.  I'm not sure that this is the correct equation to use or how to apply it if it is.  Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Where did this question come from? I've seen "relative curvature" before in the literature, but usually of one surface with respect to another...

Comment: It is a question on a homework assignment for my differential geometry class. Our textbook, which is a collection of typed lecture material from our professor, only gave the above definition so I'm uncertain as how to approach the problem.

Comment: My only guess is that "relative" here means relative to a nonstandard Gauss sphere -- you aren't taking a class on projective geometry or anything like that? And there's no hints from the notes/lectures what he means?

Comment: I don't believe the class discusses projective geometry.  I just found a section of my notes that say: k(theta,a)cos(theta) = k(0,a), where k(theta,a) is relative curvature and a is a tangent vector.